# what does format=none reference in django rest framework apiview?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Docs are here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#get_permissionsself

in this example format is set to none but no reference to it:

```
class ListUsers(APIView):
    """
    View to list all users in the system.

    * Requires token authentication.
    * Only admin users are able to access this view.
    """
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return a list of all users.
        """
        usernames = [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)
```

I checked the source code and still no reference to format.

Appreciate some clarity

Answer (score 5):

You use them in your URLs to append a suffix content type format(HTML, JSON or API). You can read about it here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#adding-optional-format-suffixes-to-our-urls